# how to add node in through Drupal API

Tags: drupal, drupal-7, content-management-system, drupal-6, drupal-modules

In order to insert an article to Drupal there are thee ways of doing that:

by admin panel - really slow and not feasable if talking about 400 articles
by pure sql - number of tables that have to maintained and calculated (content, core, cat etc.) is quite high and it's not really reliable

by using drupal API - that's something that I was trying to implement but can't find a good documentation on it. What I'm trying to achieve is to use drupal classes and insert content (ie. running a PHP file with (catid,title,introtext....))

Example: what i want to add node in xyz.com/drupal site but my php code should be run in irankmedi.com

Can you please point me into direction where I can find some info on how to manage articles and categories this way?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

If your request is very specific and you can't find a module that does what you need it shouldn't be too difficult to make a module on your own and import (create drupal) content from your code. Should be something like this:

1. Create a php file that will do the job.
2. At start of your script include standard Drupal's bootstrap code so you'll have all Drupal's functionality available in your script
3. Make code that will read content (from database or feed or something else).
4. Use Drupal api to insert node programatically:
   https://www.drupal.org/node/1388922
5. Call your script manually or set cron to call it on specific time periods.

Comment: Thank you very much for your response,  But what  i want to add node in xyz.com/drupal site but my php code should be run in irankmedi.com

Comment: You have to make some code on you xyz.com and then trigger it by some call from other site.

Answer (score 0):

First you have to read RSS feed in drupal custom module. Then, following code can create node programatically.

```
$node = new stdClass();
$node->type = 'blog';             // This type should exist
node_object_prepare($node);       // Sets some defaults.
$node->language = LANGUAGE_NONE;  // The language of the default 
$node->title = "testnode"; 
$node->body[LANGUAGE_NONE][0]['value'] = "Body"; 
node_save($node);                 // function that actually saves node in database
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your response, But what i want to add node in xyz.com/drupal site but my php code should be run in irankmedi.com